# Node.JS client-sessions: session not persisting; passing request to function

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, request

*Update

It actually only persist for a single route where the modification happened. the request session is persistent throughout the entire app...

i tried adding this, but no cigar:

```
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
}));
app.options('*', cors());

app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
```

---

so i'm using express js (node api) and i have a design pattern where i call a certain function for each route and i pass the request object to that function, like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const client_sessions = require('client-sessions');
const brain = require('./brain'); // custom module
const chamber = require('./chamber');

const app = express();

app.use(client_sessions({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: chamber.app_secret,
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
  cookie: {
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: false,
      ephemeral: false
  }
}));

app.put('/signup', function(request, response) {
  brain.sign_up(request)
  .then(obj => { return response.json(obj) })
  .catch(obj => { return response.json(obj) });
});
```

and in brain module, the signup function looks like this:

```
function sign_up(request) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var { username, email, password } = request.body

    if(!username || !email || !password) {
       return reject({error: true, message: "username, email and/or password not provided..."})
     }
    if(typeof(username) !== 'string' || typeof(email) !== 'string' || typeof(password) !== 'string') {
      return reject({error: true, message: "username, email and password must be of type string..."})
    }

    var check_username = models.Users.findOne({ where: { username } });
    var check_email = models.Users.findOne({ where: { email } });

    Promise.all([check_username, check_email])
    .then(values => {
      // console.log("signup checks: ", values);
      var username_result = values[0] ? values[0].get({plain: true}) : false;
      var email_result = values[1] ? values[1].get({plain: true}) : false;

      if(username_result) { return reject({error: true, message: "username is taken..."}); }
      if(email_result) { return reject({error: true, message: "email already in use..."}); }

      models.Users.create({ username, email, password: bcrypt.hashSync(password) })
      .then(user_data => {
        var { id, email, username, date_created, uniqueValue, bio, link, icon } = user_data.dataValues;
        var user = { id, email, username, date_created, uniqueValue, bio, link, icon };
        var session_id = chamber.uniqueValue();

        request.session.id = session_id;
        request.session.user = user;

        console.log("session --- ", request.session);
        return resolve({ user, session_id, message: "Signed Up!", online: true });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error: ", error);
        return reject({error: true, message: "error processing data..."});
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("error: ", error);
      return reject({error: true, message: "error fetching data..."});
    })
  });
}
```

the problem is that the session is not persisting between requests. i did some troublshooting and it appears to work when i modify the request.session directly in the app route callback function but not when i pass it to another function and modify it there. i should be able to do that. why doesn't is work? is it because everything is done programmatically and not through the client (browser)?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of reading and research, something a developer has to do often, i found the problem and solution. The requests i was sending to the api didn't include the credentials so the express app would create a whole new session instead of using the current one. For those who use fetch API in javascript, fetch() does not include credentials by default. To make ajax calls, make sure that the second argument (object) has this key-value pair --- credentials: "include"

so something like this:

```
 let params = {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include"
  }

  fetch($vault.api_domain + "/signout", params)
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(json => {
    self.session = json;
    return resolve(json);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("error:", error);
    return reject({error: true, message: "error fetching..."});
  });
```